# Javascript executing batch file that incorporates setting of environment variables for a per session basis

Tags: javascript, windows, batch-file

I'm working on creating a base for a batch file that is designed to 2 main things:

1. Set several environment variables
2. Executes a jscript file
3. When I exit the program that is run by the jscript file, I want the variables to unset themselves

Currently this is what I'm working with (actual variables and paths omitted):

```
SET EnvVar1=<path>
SET EnvVar2=<path>

C:\Windows\SysWOW64\wscript.exe //e:jscript "<PATH>\JSCRIPT.js"
```

Now, it appears to me that it's working, but I'm not used to writing batch files that incorporate environment variables and jscript files. When I do something similar to this and run an executable, the cmd window stays open and this confirms to me that the variables are staying set until I shut down the program. Is there anything similar that I can do with this project that would produce the same results? The intended purpose is to allow me to run multiple versions/builds of the same jscript/programs for testing purposes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SETLOCAL
SET "EnvVar1=<path>"
SET "EnvVar2=<path>"
C:\Windows\SysWOW64\wscript.exe //e:jscript "<PATH>\JSCRIPT.js"
ENDLOCAL
```

`setlocal` command generates a copy of the environment. Any changes are done inside this copy. `endlocal` discards this copy, reverting the environment to the previous state.

Comment: Thanks for the help, but unfortunately that does not seem to resolve my issue. I think I'm going to need to switch to using SETX as the variables I'm needing to set won't stay persistent and messes with the program I'm running. Seems that even if I try to incorporate a PAUSE or running a notepad instance to keep the command prompt window open these specific environment variables won't work in that fashion.

Comment: @Maddprof, sorry, but there is something i don't understand. `setx` is designed to persist variables, but in your question you indicate you want the variables unset at the end. Can you edit your question to include more information or clarify the desired behaviour?

Comment: that was my original goal - create a script that would non-persistently set variables; but the sample you provided didn't seem to work. Now it seems that even SETX is not working, but I'm fairly convinced now that its the program I'm running, not the actual setting of environment variables that is the problem. I will update my original question if I can resolve the problem I'm seeing.